# Forests in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Stumbled upon this question in a practice problem set:

> Suppose graph $G$ is a forest with $n$ vertices, $m$ edges and $T$ trees. Express $m$ in terms of $n$ and $T$.

I know that a simple graph is $G=(V,E)$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  First think about how many edges are in a tree with $n$ vertices.  Then think about what happens when you remove an edge.  Use induction.

Comment: I'd also recommend just drawing out examples of forests and trying to find a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a forest $G$ of $n = 10$ vertices and $m$ edges and $t = 3$ trees (say $T_1, T_2, T_3$). We want to solve for $m$.

To do this, we construct a new graph $G'$ from $G$ by drawing an edge from $T_1$ to $T_2$ and drawing an edge from $T_2$ to $T_3$. Observe that $G'$ now has $n' = 10$ vertices and $m' = m + 2$ edges but only $t' = 1$ tree (can you see why $G'$ is connected and acyclic?). It follows that $m' = 9$ so that $m = 7$.

Can you see how to generalize this argument?

Comment: yea i think i can see it, thanks!